# WCF throwing exception when trying to access library

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I'm a student trying to set up a WCF service. I got the host and client running with a servicelibrary, and it works fine until my client tries to call upon a service that accesses a library (Gamez) I've made. The method it calls upon works fine normally, it's just through the WCF that it suddenly crashes it.

So say it calls upon this:

```
public int AddValues(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    return c;

}
```

It'll work fine, but this:

```
    public Guid GetUserId(String userName)
    {
        Guid user = Gamez.Sql.GetIdFromUserName(userName);
        return user;
    }
```

=boom. Keep in mind that the GetIdFromUserName method works fine when called on from non-WCF-related code.

This is the client-side code:

```
namespace WCFClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.Open();
            String gameName = "Liksomspill";
            String userName = "Grouse";
            //int result = client.GetHighScore(userName, gameName);
            //Console.WriteLine("highscoren er: {0}", result);
            //Guid result = client.GetUserId(userName);
            //Console.WriteLine("blablabla: {0}", result);

            int a = 5;
            int b = 2;
            int result2 = client.AddValues(a, b);
            Console.WriteLine("highscoren er {0}", result2);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work fine as long as it stays like this (so it'll return 7), but if I remove commenting from these lines:

```
        Guid result = client.GetUserId(userName);
        Console.WriteLine("blablabla: {0}", result);
```

the top line will throw an exception, but I have no idea what it is as it only says "FaultException`1 was unhandled" with subtext "The type initializer for 'Gamez.Sql' threw an exception.". I've tried looking this up, but I don't really understand how to fix this (I'm coding in Visual Studio 2012). Here are some of the links I found on the subject, but it's just massively confusing me:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1829b844-1237-4390-8d36-76a7e42a64d3/

http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/systemservicemodelfaultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code/

I'm sure there is just something basic which I am completely overseeing (...you are supposed to be able to call libraries with the wcf service, right? Or do I have to incorporate the parts of my library I want to use into the service library?). I've added references to the library so that shouldn't be a problem. I'm sorry if this question is kinda stupid, but I'm tearing myself apart in frustration after banging my head against the issue for six hours.

If you need some background information, I'm basically trying to set up an API for games uploaded to a website I'm making (so the games can extract/insert highscores, etc. from the database).

Thank you so much for your time.

If needed, here is the host code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfServiceLibrary;
using System.ServiceModel.Description; 

namespace WCFHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/WCF");

            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);

            ServiceDebugBehavior debug = selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();

            if (debug == null)
            {
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(
         new ServiceDebugBehavior() { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
            }
            else
            {
                if (!debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)
                {
                    debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                //selfHost.Open();
                selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "Service1Service");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready");
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to terminate service");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                selfHost.Close();

            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occured: {0}", ce.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ServiceLibrary code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using Gamez;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {


        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public void SetHighScore(int score, String userName)
        {

        }
        public int GetHighScore(String userName, String gameName)
        {
            int score = Gamez.Sql.getHighScore(userName, gameName);
            return score;    
        }
        public Guid GetUserId(String userName)
        {
            Guid user = Gamez.Sql.GetIdFromUserName(userName);
            return user;
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
        public int AddValues(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = a + b;
            return c;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this: Start your service under debugger (VS2012). Go to menu Debug > Exceptions. In the dialog, check all check-boxes under `thrown` column. Then run your client. It will take you the place where the exception occurs and tell you what exactly it is.

Comment: @YK1
Hi, thanks for your reply. I did what you said and ran both the host and the client again. I get the same error. I have to run the host outside of debug mode, though, as I can't run both at the same time (in debug mode, so ctrl+f5 for the host, then I run the client in debug mode). Maybe that's why?

Comment: You got to run host under debugger. Need not run client under debugger. Just run it on command line.

Comment: @YK1
Thank you so much, this brings me closer to a solution. The library I'm talking about is a SQL library with lots of calls, and apparantly it breaks when it tries to set the connection string 
        `public static string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webtek.uia.no"].ConnectionString;` in the library itself. It gives me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I don't understand why, though, as this line runs correctly when I call from it from my webpage code.

Comment: Check connection strings in your web page's web.config. Those must be copied to app.config of the wcf host.

Comment: @YK1 
I talked to the person responsible for the SQL side of the project, and this line fetches the connectionString from the web.config file in the website code project. I'm guessing that's why it doesn't work, as the ServiceLibrary tries to talk directly to the SQL library. Do you have a suggestion on how to confront such a problem?

Comment: @YK1 You resopnded while I was writing my last post. I'll try that and come back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: @YK1 As another question: How would you suggest running the Host on a server? All the tutorials I've found uses console (.cs), but I assume it's not a good solution to just let a console window run on it. Is it possible to integrate the host into the website somehow?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30606/discussion-between-user1339253-and-yk1)

Comment: @YK1 If you put up an answer I'll accept it as the solution. Thanks again, you deserve the credit.